# Add a field to coupon settings and display the value on Woocommerce admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, coupon

I am having some really hard times trying to make it work.
I've had an idea in back of my head to:

1. be able to assign single user to a coupon code through an extra field in general coupon tab, which is listing unassigned users to coupon codes

   I dont want to use third party extensions, custom-fields, etc. I was hoping I'll be able to do it through meta data but I failed. Not sure how to get it done properly.
2. add two extra columns on orders page and display both coupon code and user assigned to it.

   After some time reading docs and xDebugging in phpstorm I have also failed to get it done.

   ```
    function order_sellers_and_coupons_columns_values($column)
    {
       global $post, $the_order;

       if ($column == 'order_coupon_code') {
           $coupons = $the_order->get_used_coupons(); // not sure how to get coupon object by the coupon code
           echo (count($coupons)) ? $coupons[0] : '';
       }
    }

    // even though I see the order objects have an items and coupon lines property, 
    // which is an object, i can't get access to it
    $the_order->items["coupon_lines"]
   ```

I am not asking for ready-to-go solution, but to show me the way how to get it done.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In WooCommerce admin single coupon pages, we add an extra field for the seller *(dealer)*:

```
// Add a custom field to Admin coupon settings pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options', 'add_coupon_text_field', 10 );
function add_coupon_text_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'                => 'seller_id',
        'label'             => __( 'Assing a seller (dealer)', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'       => '',
        'description'       => __( 'Assign a seller / dealer to a coupon', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,

    ) );
}

// Save the custom field value from Admin coupon settings pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 'save_coupon_text_field', 10, 2 );
function save_coupon_text_field( $post_id, $coupon ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['seller_id'] ) ) {
        $coupon->update_meta_data( 'seller_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['seller_id'] ) );
        $coupon->save();
    }
}
```

Then using the following you will add to admin orders list the coupon code (when it's used in the order) with the seller / dealer name:

```
// Adding a new column to admin orders list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column' );
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    // Inserting columns to a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            // Inserting after "Status" column
            $reordered_columns['coupons'] = __( 'Coupon','theme_domain');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding used coupon codes
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
    global $the_order;

    if ( $column == 'coupons' ) {
        $coupons = (array) $the_order->get_used_coupons();
        $dealers = [];

        foreach( $coupons as $coupon_code ) {
            $coupon    = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
            $dealers[] = $coupon->get_meta('seller_id');
        }

        if( count($coupons) > 0 )
            echo implode( ', ', $coupons );

        if( count($dealers) > 0 )
            echo '<br><small>(' . implode( ', ', $dealers ) . ')</small>';
    }
}
```

All code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**On Admin coupon single pages:**

[image]

**On Admin edit orders list:**

[image]

Comment: thanks once again Loic :) 
not sure if I put that clear enough. 

Instead of restricting coupons to users (shop clients), I would like to assing coupons to my sellers / dealers, so everytime some of our client use a coupon code, I will know that this is the client of one of my dealers.

I dont also want to use more than just one coupon for just one order. Just want to use them as identifiers.

Comment: Loic, you're amazing!

Just tested your code and it works like a charm.
I have so much to learn - really appreciate your skills and help.

Comment: already did both, is there anything else I can do for you? :)

Comment: Is there a way to show the field only if a specific coupon type is selected? E.g only if fixed cart is selected.